# Compare Culture-Invaliant and ignore Superscript

Tags: c#

A database with collation ...CI_AS makes no differences between "²" and "2".

The c# default String-Comparer StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase on the other hand makes a difference.

so if I want to save an object to the database, theres a unique error.

What is the common solution to say c# to not make any difference? (Own Comparer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, custom equality comparer ([IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)) should do the job, using it you'll be able to compare your strings in a way you need

Comment: Isn't there any .Net comparer, wich can handle this?